# bitbucket add notifications to all repositories

Tags: notifications, bitbucket, administration

I have more than 100 repositories in BitBucket. I want to subscribe to all notifications to all respositories. I can do it one by one (go to each respository -> '...' option -> manage notifications -> select all notifications)

[image]

[image]

but maybe someone know a way to do it to all resposiories of a project.
Can someone help me? Thanks for your time.
Jon

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Bitbucket Server, one way to do this is fetch all the repository names and loop through them and send a request to `watch` all the repos. This query can be further filtered with query parameters defined in the api docs.

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v811/api-group-repository/#api-api-latest-repos-get

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/rest/v811/api-group-repository/#api-api-latest-projects-projectkey-repos-repositoryslug-watch-post

- store the output of all the repo names in a variable `DATA` as an array of objects with keys `project` and `repo`. These are the path variables required to create a new `watch` request
- loop over each object and `POST` a request to `.../watch`
- in the `POST`, the `X-Atlassian-Token` header is required because Atlassian api checks for CSRF validation and will send an error, if omitted. *This should only be used for cli requests.*
  https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloudkb/xsrf-check-failed-when-calling-cloud-apis-826874382.html

```bash
#!/bin/bash

baseUrl=""
apiKey=""
readarray -t data < <(curl -X GET https://$baseUrl/rest/api/latest/repos \
   -H "accept: application/json" \
   -H "authorization: Bearer $apiKey" \
   -H "cache-control: no-store" \
   | jq -c ' .values[] | {repo: .slug, project: .project.key} ')

for repos in "${data[@]}"

do
repo=$(jq -r ' .repo' <<< $repos)
proj=$(jq -r ' .project' <<< $repos)

echo -e "Processing $repo : $proj"

curl -X POST https://$baseUrl/rest/api/latest/projects/$proj/repos/$repo/watch \
  -H "authorization: Bearer $apiKey" \
  -H "X-Atlassian-Token: no-check"
done;
```

there is one small issue on Atlassian's side when using the api. The `Manage Account > Watched repositories` doesn't seem to update after this operation. If you view the actual repository, you will see the `Watching` icon is updated.

I filed a bug with them https://support.atlassian.com/requests/CA-2562481/

Comment: Thank you Jeremy! It's a very complet answer, but I'm using cloud. I thought thre was soe option i didn´t know, but maybe it's not so easy.

Comment: unfortunately, it appears they don't have an operation to modify the list of watchers in the cloud v2 api. I only see the GET operation. https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/bitbucket/rest/api-group-repositories/#api-repositories-workspace-repo-slug-watchers-get

Comment: Thanks again Jeremy. I think I'll do it by hand.